# React Admin - Get additional parameter from server and pass to List view props

Tags: react-admin

We get "total" and "data" from getList which is passed to List view. I want to show additional data Aside of list view, Eg. total sell, total amount etc. I can pass those data from server but it seems react admin ignore those parameters. How can i accept those parameters from server and pass to Aside props in List view?

Answer (score 0):

If the API is RESTful, adding additional data to the response would break REST principles. You could expose a different endpoint for such "summary" information and call it form a custom component.